# Can't find certain elements from Yahoo News using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to collect comments from Yahoo News and having trouble finding the text element of the comments section using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
test = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/cdc-advisers-recommend-spring-covid-215003196.html"

# open comments
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(test)

comment_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="link caas-button noborder caas-tooltip flickrComment caas-comment top"]')
comment_button.click()
```

I could click the comments button (so that it opens) and there's no problem up to this part. However, I have trouble finding the text of the comments section.

[screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIeNj.png)

The red part is an example of what I want to find and here is the condensed html of this part.

```
<div class="components-MessageContent-index__messageEntitiesWrapper">
   <div class="components-MessageContent-components-MessageEntities-MessageEntities__message-entities components-MessageContent-components-MessageEntities-MessageEntities__is-column">
      <span class="Typography__text--11-4-15 Typography__t4--11-4-15 Typography__l6--11-4-15">
         <div data-spot-im-class="message-text">
            <p>...</p>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried with different elements as below, but none of them worked.

```
# 1
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="components-MessageContent-index__messageEntitiesWrapper"]')

# 2
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="components-MessageContent-components-MessageEntities-MessageEntities__message-entities components-MessageContent-components-MessageEntities-MessageEntities__is-column"]')

# 3
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="Typography__text--11-4-15 Typography__t4--11-4-15 Typography__l6--11-4-15"]')

# 4
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-spot-im-class="message-text"]')
```

I also tried

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '')
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '')
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '')
```

But they didn't work either. I got an error message saying like this;

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="components-MessageContent-index__messageEntitiesWrapper"]"}
```

Did I input the Xpath incorrectly, or should I use a different syntax other than Xpath? Or is it basically impossible to scrape the comments section of this website using Selenium? I'd appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the comments elements are inside a shadow-root. To access them, you'll need to switch into the shadow-root element and then find the element(s) you want.

```
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#spotim-specific > div > div')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
message = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.components-MessageContent-index__messageEntitiesWrapper')
```